# Laravel Model - Calculate avg ratings

Tags: php, laravel, rating

I have table "Orders" where rating score is stored, and inside that table i have relation with places.

I need to grab order rating from each place and calculate the average rating score. I need it on model so I can grab it for later use.

This is the scheme:

**[ORDERS]**

--order_id = 10

--place_id = 2

--rating = 3

**[PLACES]**

--place_id = 2

So, when i call: $place->avgRating(),it needs to return 4.3 for example. Pulling the order information is working. Here is the code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model
{
    public function user(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function orders(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
    }



}
```

Comment: Can you show some code or table screenshot?

Comment: @Laravel - 

Order table: http://prntscr.com/pbcszf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the collection methods in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-average).

So add a method in your `Place` model:

```
public function avgRating()
{
    return $this->orders->avg('rating');
}
```

Calling `$project->avgRating();` should return what you expect.

Comment: @НиколаР. please accept the answer then :) happy coding.